# Laravel latest not working (not appearing in my SQL query)

Tags: php, laravel

So I have a Student model with this function:

```
public function latestStatus()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(StatusStudent::class)->latest();
    }
```

then I just do a query with this latestStatus()

```
$query = Student::findOrFail(1);
            $query = $query->whereHas('latestStatus', function($query) use ($statusuri) {
                $query->where('status_id', 1);
            });
            dd($query->toSql());
```

and the toSql() function returns:

```
"select * from `students` where exists (select * from `status_student` where `students`.`id` = `status_student`.`student_id` and `status_id` = ?)
```

as if latest() is ignored.

Why doesn't latest() add anything to the query?

Thanks.

Edit:

I tried adding selectRaw for example:

```
public function latestStatus()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(StatusStudent::class)->selectRaw('MAX(status_student.id)');
    }
```

and still nothing appears in my query.

Comment: `findOrFail()` returns a model, not a query builder.

Comment: its a where exists query so ordering it doesn't matter ...

Answer (score 1):

If you dig deeper to the `whereHas()` relationship. It calls the `has()` method then if you look for the `has()` method you will see the `getRelationWithoutConstraints()` method, means that it will call the relationship but it will remove all the constraints attach to it and will only call the base query instance :

```
public function latestStatus()
{
    return $this->hasOne(StatusStudent::class)->latest(); // the latest() will be removed in the query if you call the `latestStatus` using the `whereHas() or has()`
}
```

so if you use the `whereHas()` like the way you use it :

```
"select * from `students` where exists (select * from `status_student` where `students`.`id` = `status_student`.`student_id` and `status_id` = ?)
```

it will return the query with out the `latest()`.

Instead of doing it like that you can do it like :

**Student Model**

```
public function status() : HasOne
{
    return $this->hasOne(StatusStudent::class);
}
```

**Controller**

```
$student = Student::findOrFail(1);

$student->whereHas('status', function($query) {
    $query->where('status_id', 1)
        ->latest();
})
```

But since the relationship is define as `one-to-one` :

```
$student = Student::findOrFail(1);

$student->load('status');
```

or

```
$student = Student::findOrFail(1)->status()->get();
```

Maybe you want to get the latest of all the status.

```
StudentStatus::query()->latest()->get();
```

Answer (score -1):

As stated in a [comment by @matticustard](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/131949890?noredirect=1),

> `findOrFail()` returns a model, not a query builder.

Instead of `findOrFail(1)` use `where('id', 1)`

Comment: that may be true but it isn't the problem as `$query` is the builder after it is reassigned

Comment: It returns the `Student` model that that extends  `Model`. So when you call a `Builder` method using the `Student` model it will resolve the method and return the same as `Query Builder`.